# Spring Data Neo4j session caches all entities retrieved from the database

Tags: neo4j, transactions, spring-data, out-of-memory

I have a Spring Boot application, which uses Neo4j driver through String data to query the database. The nature of the application is such that it need to iterate through virtually all the database nodes. The application invariable crashes with an OutOfMemoryError.

The application has a service which calls Neo4j in a loop each time retrieving on the order of 10,000 entities from the database.

Investigation of the application behavior in VisualVM memory profiles showed that Neo4J session appears to be holding to all the entities retrieved in all the iterations. This is clearly not the desired behavior. The application is read-only it does not intend to make any changes to these entities.

We tried different changes related to transaction behavior - not using @Transactional annotation, marking transactions as read-only, nothing changes the fact that entities retrieved from the database are not garbage-collected.

How do I turn off the transactional behavior or otherwise make the Neo4j driver to stop holding on to the entities read from Neo4j using declarative Cypher queries.